# Updating table data through procedure in JPA

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, persistence

I am developing a project with JSF, JAVA and JPA. My database is MySql 5.5. I have generated entity clases and entity pages using Netbean 7.0 wizard.

When I update data with update page, then I found updated data in view page.

But I have another page where I am updating a table data through a stored procedure. I am taking data from a JSF form page and sending as parameter to the stored procedure from backing bean. I found in database, that the data is updated, but in front end I found no updated data. It showing previous data.

When I am recompiling the project,then it is showing updated data.

Can anyone help me please, what's the wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

So you update data using a stored proc and expect that the JPA implementation has psychic powers to know this ? It can't know about it if you do it without its knowledge.

Just call "refresh()" on the objects retrieved and they get any updated values, or write some logic that removes all objects updated by the stored proc from the JPA cache(s)